# jquery sending form data and a json object in an ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I'm making a call to another ajax page, the call posts a json object.
I also need to send data from a form 
(not using submit - I have the ajax call attached to a button which uses `e.preventDeault()`).

The call is as folows:

```
var myUrl = 'sendswatch-data.php';
            $.ajax({
                url: myUrl,
                data: {'swatchid[]':swatchArray}, 'formdata':$('#orderData').serialize()},
                type: "POST",
                error: function(xhr, statusText, errorThrown){
                    // Work out what the error was and display the appropriate message
                },
                success: function(myData){
                    $('#tabsampleorder').html(myData);
                    $('.tabber').hide();
                    $('#tabsampleorder').show();
                }
            });
```

I have a form on the page id of formdata.

How do I send this as well as the json object? I've tried

```
data: {'swatchid[]':swatchArray}, 'formdata':$('#orderData').serialize()},
```

but that's generating an error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have an extra } after watchArray. Try removing that.

```
data: {'swatchid[]':swatchArray, 'formdata':$('#orderData').serialize()},
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this that doesn't require you to explicitly name the field name ('formdata') as a key?

Answer (score 2):

You can send data from the form as follows:

```
data : { swatchid: swatchArray, formdata: $('#orderData').serialize() }
```

You will need a parameter in the controller for every field that your add.