# How to pass FormData and JSON object in ajax to Spring MVC Controller?

Tags: json, ajax, spring-mvc, form-data

I need to pass both FormData and JSON object in an ajax call, but I get a 400 Bad Request error.

```
[artifact:mvn]  org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver - Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: Unexpected character ('-' (code 45)) in numeric value: expected digit (0-9) to follow minus sign, for valid numeric value
[artifact:mvn]  at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@3c0d58f6; line: 1, column: 3]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('-' (code 45)) in numeric value: expected digit (0-9) to follow minus sign, for valid numeric value
[artifact:mvn]  at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@3c0d58f6; line: 1, column: 3]
```

JS:

```
var formData = new FormData(form[0]);
//form JSON object
var jsonData = JSON.stringify(jcArray);
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: postDataUrl,
        data: { formData:formData,jsonData:jsonData },
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        headers: { 
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
        },
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        }
});
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/processSaveItem",method = RequestMethod.POST")
public @ResponseBody Map<String,String> processSaveItem(
                                  @RequestBody XYZClass result[])

}
```

There is similar question, [jquery sending form data and a json object in an ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5938544/1793718) and I'm trying the same way.

How can I send both FormData and JSON object in a single ajax request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by appending the JSON string with FormData object in ajax POST.

```
var jsonObjectData = JSON.stringify(jcArray);
formData.append("jsonObjectData",jsonObjectData);
```

and in controller you can access it the normal way as you do for other form data values.

```
request.getParameter("jsonObjectData");
```

and now you'll be having the Stringified JSON and you can parse the json to Java object

[How to parse a JSON string to an array using Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7246157/how-to-parse-a-json-string-to-an-array-using-jackson).

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in this way

```
   postdata={};
   postdata.formData=formData;
   postData.jsonData=jsonData
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: postDataUrl,
    data: { postdata},
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    headers: { 
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
    },
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    }
```

});

and controller side you can identify the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following to pass form data in Ajax call.

```
var formData = $('#client-form').serialize();
$.ajax({
    url: 'www.xyz.com/index.php?' + formData,
    type: 'POST',
    data:{
    },
    success: function(data){},
    error: function(data){},
})
```

Comment: lol. This is not what I wanted. How does this answer my question and Where is the json data in your answer?

Comment: In data section you can pass json object with reference and form data is being appended in URL section.
For example, 
data:{jsonObject: JsonObject
    },

Comment: You didn't understand my question properly. I need to send both json object and formData together. Your response implies that you are sending only one of them.

Comment: Here I am sending my form data also. I am passing my form data in Url.